# response not getting cached because of faulty headers

Tags: browser-cache, response-headers

one of the request of my web page is to retrieve the html panel data. This request is triggered with the help of java script from browser. The response received from the server include caching headers that are confusing. The headers received are like - Cache-Control:"private, max-age=120no-store"

in this expected is max-age=120 header but we are getting no-store header as well which is causing the response not to remain cached.

Can anyone let me know what all we can do to avoid the no-store in the cache-control header?

As max-age and no-store are not separated by any separator, what we can do to know what is causing them to appear in this format and fix the issue?

Comment: How could we _possibly_ know, if you have given us virtually no relevant information at all …? What CMS is used, what web server, ...? Has the web server admin been asked about this yet?

Comment: webserver was IHS http server and application server used was websphere-portal in this case